# can't access component's methods with vue js

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

i am trying to make a sidebar menu kinda thing in vue js with toggle methods,
so when i click on a link it use the v-on attribute to access a method from the instance.
In this method, i emit the word 'isToggled' and then my menu component should detect the emit with v-on:isToggled="toggle". But it doesn't access this toggle method.
main.js code :

```
    Vue.component("shop-list", {
  template: `<div class="shop-list">
    <transition name="fade">
        <div>
           <div class="row shop-header">
               <h3 class="col-10">Panier</h3>
               <a class="col-2" href="#" @on:click="toggle">X</a>
           </div> 
           <div>
            <p>votre panier est vide</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
    </div>`,


    data: function () {
        return {
          isActive: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        toggle() {
          console.log("sa marche !");
          this.isActive = !this.isActive;
        },
      },
    });

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app", // el = element
  methods: {
    navToggle() {
      this.$emit("isToggled");
      console.log("isCliked");
    },
  },
});
```

html code :

```
    <div id="app">
        <shop-list v-if="isActive" v-on:isToggled="this.toggle">

        </shop-list>
        <header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0083/4856/5568/files/QUELAFAMILLE.svg?v=1587044097">
                </div>
                <div class="col-4" id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Catalogue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Look Book</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mon compte</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 shop-cart">
                    <a v-on:click="navToggle"><i class="icon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 22px;"></i> 
   </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Your code has no `$emit` call, it does not reflect your description.

Comment: Yes i forgot to put it in here but the emit is working.

Comment: i got this error in my console: [Vue warn]: Property or method "isActive" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the bindings and the emit the wrong way. Right now your App component is emitting an event that no component is listening. And you are trying to use the `isActive` property of the ShopList component in the parent.

What you want to do is actually emit an event from the ShopList component and react to that event on the App component. The code would be something like...

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app", // el = element
  data: function () {
    return {
      showListIsActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShopList() {
      this.shopListIsActive = !this.shopListIsActive
    },
  },
});

Vue.component("shop-list", {
  template: `<div class="shop-list">
    <transition name="fade">
      <div>
        <div class="row shop-header">
          <h3 class="col-10">Panier</h3>
          <a class="col-2" href="#" @on:click="toggle">X</a>
        </div> 
        <div>
          <p>votre panier est vide</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>`,

  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.$emit('toggle')
    }
  },
});
```

Note the changes:

- isActive moved to the App component as shopListIsActive
- ShopList emits the 'toggle' event

Now your app's template would be:

```
<div id="app">
  <shop-list v-if="shopListIsActive" v-on:toggle="this.toggleShopList">
  </shop-list>

  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0083/4856/5568/files/QUELAFAMILLE.svg?v=1587044097">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Catalogue</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Look Book</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mon compte</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 shop-cart">
        <a v-on:click="toggleShopList"><i class="icon-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 22px;"></i>
```

Now the App controls if the ShopList component is shown or not and listens to the `toggle` event emitted by the ShopList to hide it.

Note that the `v-if` directive expect `shopListIsActive` to be a property of the element that uses that component, that's why you have that error saying `isActive` is not defined on your code, it's defined INSIDE the ShopList component but you are using if from outside it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, i tried your code and it works, you're the answer i've been looking for :). So the communication between a component and the App only works in one way. anyway, thank you a lot

Comment: Communication works both ways. Binding/props for parent => child, emit/event listener for child => parent.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the shorthand v-on syntax.
You simply need to change the syntax to:

`<a @click="toggle"> </a>`
The point of the shorthand is to omit the v-on/on keyword and just use the `@` for events and `:` for binging

Examples:

```
<!-- Regular v-on -->
<a v-on:click="coolMethod"> Wow </a>

<!-- Shorthand @[insert-event-name-here] -->
<a @click="coolMethod"> Much </a>
```

Check out the docs [here for more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand) info.

As for your example, I think you've got some code pollution going on. I recreated your code with just the method + showing that the `@click="toggle"` does work and reach the component's method. See code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div id="app">
   <div class="shop-list">
      <transition name="fade">
        <div>
           <div class="row shop-header">
               <h3 class="col-10">Panier</h3>
               <a class="col-2" href="#" @click="toggle">X</a>
           </div> 
           <div>
            <p>votre panier est vide</p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
     data: function () {
        return {
          isActive: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        toggle() {
          console.log("sa marche !");
          alert("sa marche !")
        },
      },
  
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes i know about those shortcut, i just tried every way to do it ‍♂️.

Comment: Ow i just realises what you meant, sorry. But yeah still doesn’t fix my problem.

Comment: I think you may have your vue instance set up wrong. Try starting from scratch. I wrore your code from scratch and added an alert. See example above

Comment: okay so i made it work thanks to you but now the shop-list thing is not a component so i don't know how to make it work while it's a component.